# Typescript map union of objects to union of objects

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I wrote some typescript code and I am not quiet sure why it is not working as I expected.
I would really appriopriate if someone would explain me what I do wrong or what other approach should I use.

Let's say I have a `Definition` of a function `name` and `data`.

```
interface Definition<TName extends string, TData extends any> {
  name: TName;
  data: TData;
}
```

`Definition` at some point changes into `Action`. `Action` has a function named `method` with `payload` as first paramater type.

```
interface Action<TDefinition extends Definition<string, any>> {
  name: TDefinition["name"];
  method: (data: TDefinition["data"]) => void;
}
```

Keep in mind that all `Definition` union elements must move through `Changer`.

```
interface Changer<TDefinition extends Definition<string, any>> {
  actions: Action<TDefinition>[];
}
```

```
interface Definition<TName extends string, TData extends any> {
  name: TName;
  data: TData;
}

interface Action<TDefinition extends Definition<string, any>> {
  name: TDefinition["name"];
  method: (data: TDefinition["data"]) => void;
}

interface Changer<TDefinition extends Definition<string, any>> {
  actions: Action<TDefinition>[];
}

const set: Changer<Definition<"one", 1> | Definition<"two", 2>> = {
  actions: [
    {
      name: "one",
      method: (data) => data, // data type is equal to '1 | 2' I would expect it to be '1'
    },
  ],
};

set.actions[0].method(1); // data type is equal to '1 | 2' I would expect it to be '1'
```

Could you tell me what should I do to achieve result I expect?

I am thinking new `Definition`, however I belive I may have some issues because of `[key: string]: any`.

```
interface Definition<TName extends string, TData extends { [key: string]: any }> {
  [key in TName]: TData[key]
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Why using a union type for `set`?

Comment: `set` is just a variable name - it does not matter, there is no more meaning behind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

```
interface Changer<TDefinition extends Definition<string, any>> {
  actions: (
    TDefinition extends infer U extends Definition<string, any> 
      ? Action<U> 
      : never
  )[];
}
```

We basically want to change the type of `actions` from

```
actions: Action<Definition<"one", 1> | Definition<"two", 2>>[]
```

to the type

```
actions: (Action<Definition<"one", 1>> | Action<Definition<"two", 2>>)[]
```

This can be done by forcing the union elements of `TDefinition` to be distributed by a conditional to individual `Actions`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAIteFSVAPbgA8AKgHKIC260AHjOACYDOaLksEA5gDRqkMiSIjT1GrNInABPAHxoA3sDRpw1aAC4BlGgG4VaJsMTbBJgwF8QYKHCSo0AQWT4iZLDnB5C4MQ2hmNk9cNxIOLnA%20KVk5BWVVdRozEO8wgG0AIiToTIBdA1UaSAALAiZtAApjERTsUN8smsR8gEo0AF4FADcCUCYrGwgYBBR0AGES6W44D3q0338JYPmfdwiefml5eMMUMJYqw1VBVbClwMkIeDg0AFULoMwz32INqK3YtGPVNAB%20ZyuV53BQ-VTacDQbpwQytdIFYDWYCQGQAB3QAFE6KjpEwyAoOgJHldwDdYPd-ko0OkANJoCBoADW0BkBHg9zy2jutLyaEsaAhUJhyLR6FIAAZOmgsTjmMRJtNZqk1iRMkRcvwAIwKAA%20zy8KuImUgAHcCJl%20AAmOJyEDIIgcdjQSDaBVRJUvdxqyEWtDatB65VhI2m81WuJShJSIEO7TpH5R35qDTab0asFoYplCpoaomdpdIwmfgAehLRZEaBR6PpbGgAEcAK6IAA2VYIaAA5JqA2hLZ20ABJNBmxstpj%20dGuemQdtoABG6G7nZ%20ll4CYzOVToYtGaz5SqzQLCmaq8MeXXlgMwBYzoAdPtfCx0uK8nf90xKprWno0GWK6I1boKAdZNq2c7dr2-ZDiOBBjhO9BTrOeBzouXaap2QA)

---

Now we have the correct type for the parameters in the functions.

```
const set: Changer<Definition<"one", 1> | Definition<"two", 2>> = {
  actions: [
    {
      name: "one",
      method: (data) => data, // data: 1
    },
    {
      name: "two",
      method: (data) => data // data: 2
    }
  ],
};
```

But this statement won't work:

```
set.actions[0].method(1); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

The `set` variable simply does not have information about individual array elements because you gave it an **explicit type**. To solve this you could create the `set` with a generic function.